# Server does not show recent changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, apache2

I'm developing a Ruby on Rails project related to semantic technology, and I'm making something basic that allow the uploading of files and searching in those files.

So far it's all working out ok, but I have noticed that when I make changes to my code files or haml files, I don't see those changes on the webserver. Only after either rebooting the server or mashing the F5 button like crazy, the changes come through. And even that is not guaranteed.

The server is running on a local, virtual, ubuntu system. This is an Apache2 webserver configured with Passenger. The website is visibile, it's just not always the latest changes.

Anyone have an idea what might be causing this, or how I can fix this?

Comment: Are you caching? The views must be getting cached. Check your caching strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config/environments/environment_name.rb file it's likely that you have these lines:

```
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Which you can switch to have the behavior you want.
If you don't want to change these then you can just touch tmp/restart, which will push the changes through (it's quicker and more graceful then restarting the web server)

To change the environment passenger runs in add the following line to your vhost:

```
RailsEnv development
```

Comment: it seems to be running production the whole time. How can I force it to run into development?

Comment: Added, but still only getting an 'something went wrong page' and the application still keeps writing in the production.log....

Started GET "/" for 192.168.33.82 at Thu Apr 07 00:29:02 -0700 2011
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):

On every request. So i have no idea what's going wrong now

Comment: The wrong number of arguments is a rails error. Do you have the line of code that is causing this (perhaps in your controller?). I presume you've restarted apache,

Comment: I have no idea. I was hoping to find that out with the stacktrace, but all I get is those 2 lines. Perhaps if the bloody thing would start running in development mode, i'd see more...

Comment: One thing to try is to replace the contents of your production.rb with development.rb. This may give you more details... ALthough this isn't a good solution to you not being able to run in dev mode. perhaps that's another question to be asked.

Comment: ArgumentError in SearchEnginesController#search
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

But that function body is empty......

Comment: I would try creating a new question on here, with your exact problem. It's not to do with your apache/passenger set up

Answer (score 0):

I was using React in my rails app, I run the following command "yarn build", before running rails server and the changes reflected.

I guess rails s or rails server command doesn't compile JavaScript files